# Lazy loading component in React using IntersectionObserver and HTML <template> tag issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to write a component that unwraps content which is placed in a HTML `<template>` tag, using IntersectionObserver. Here's my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const templates = document.querySelectorAll('template');

  function unwrap(wrapper) {
    // Place childNodes in document fragment
    const docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
      
    while (wrapper.firstChild) {
      const child = wrapper.removeChild(wrapper.firstChild);
      docFrag.appendChild(child);
    }
  
    // Replace wrapper with document fragment
    wrapper.parentNode.replaceChild(docFrag, wrapper);
  }

  let observer = new IntersectionObserver (
    entries => entries.forEach(entry => {
      if(entry.isIntersecting) {
        entry.target.unwrap(templates)
      }
    }),
    {
      rootMargin: '0px 0px 200px 0px'
    }
  )
  observer.observe(templates)
}, []);
```

I've had a look at multiple code examples and can't figure out why I'm getting this error?

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'IntersectionObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.

Any help or input would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you log `templates` to the console right before `observer.observe(templates)`, what does it return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, *templates* is a **NodeListOf < Element>**.
It's a list of elements. You need to break down it thus you can 'observe' each element (not the list of elements).

```
templates.forEach((templateElement: Element) => {
  observer.observe(templateElement);
});
```